# Responsive Slides: Showing/Hiding Buttons

Tags: css, responsive-slides

I am using the Responsive Slides plugin.

I am using a slideshow on my front page, and I didn't want the small circles, or guide "buttons" to show. I hid them by rendering them essentially transparent using CSS.

However, I am putting another slideshow on a different page of the site, and on this page I DO want these buttons to show. Is there a way to have these buttons show on one slideshow but not another?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a different css file for your slideshows. Use slideshow.css and slideshow-hidden-controls.css for example.

Comment: Thank you for your help! A related question: do you have any advice on how to get this button navigation to stay put in one place--not shift up and down under slides of different heights? I appreciate your feedback.